# SiftDescriptorExtractor causes a memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, opencv, sift

I am currently implementing SIFT to extract feature points from an image and noticed that I have a memory leak when I get the descriptors. Is there anyway I can free the memory that may be attached in the class?

**EDIT**
Added more details to the code block

```
cv::SiftFeatureDetector* features = new cv::SiftFeatureDetector();
cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor* extractor = new cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor();

std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> KeyPoints;
cv::Mat Descriptors;

// Turn the image into a Mat
cv::Mat mImage = cv::Mat(iplImage);

printf("Searching for keypoints in: %s.\n", szName.c_str());

// Detect keypoints
features->detect(mImage, KeyPoints);

printf("Found %d keypoints.\n", KeyPoints.size());

// Extract descriptors
extractor->compute(mImage, KeyPoints, Descriptors);

printf("Found %d descriptors.\n\n", Descriptors.rows);

// Let my memory go!
delete extractor;
delete features;
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are all these variables? Declare them so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post to further explain the code.

Comment: How did you come up with the conclusion that you have a memory leak in this code? I would like to know how you measured that.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and am using Visual Leak Detector. I show no leaks until I run the 'extractor->compute' function. If I comment it out I get no issues. I'd hate to run the function several times on different images knowing that I am getting a leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are right**. I just tested on Linux with **OpenCV 2.3 and there's a memory leak on** `compute()` indeed. This affects *SiftDescriptorExtractor*, and probably other types too, like *SurfDescriptorExtractor*, *OrbDescriptorExtractor* and *BriefDescriptorExtractor*.

By the way, don't forget to `cvReleaseImage()` the image you call `iplImage` at the end of this code.

Comment: Oops, sorry about not including my OpenCV version, but you are right, it is 2.3. Looks like I'm going to have to track the culprit and modify the CV source files to build a new lib and dll from it. Thanks for verifying the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Working with 2.3 too and also experience memory leaks with SiftDescriptorExtractor.
However the other descriptor extractors does not have this issue.
I suggest to create a ticket in the bugtracker to inform the developers.